# "Over years of" or "over the years of"?

Tags: articles, definite-article

Could you tell me if need to use *the* before *years* in the context below?

> Over years of working with people Kate has learned how to establish a rapport with people.
>
> Over **the** years of working with people Kate has learned how to establish a rapport with people.

I've seen *years* used with both the and without in similar contexts. Are both natural and with no difference in meaning?

Comment: "Over [many] years of working with people..." or "Over the years she has been working with people..." Using the definite article requires you to say which years you are talking about.- but I'd suggest you don't use _people_ twice in the sentence!

Comment: Thanks for the comment, but I still can't see the difference between my two examples.

Comment: Using the definite article implies that you are referring to a particular number of years.